# Setting visibility of columns of Attribute Table in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

Is there a possibility in QGIS setting a field (column) of the Attribute Table to not visible?

In the properties-dialogue of the layer, I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The option you want is under 'Layer properties', but depending on the version it's either under:

1. Layer Properties
2. Fields
3. Select 'Line Edit' in field(column) which you want to hide
4. Select 'Hidden'

Or in QGIS 3.8.2 it's:

1. Layer Properties
2. Attributes Form
3. Select the column you want to hide under 'Fields'
4. Select 'Hidden' under 'Widget Type'

[image]

Comment: Perhaps useful to someone at some point, the equivalent using PyQGIS [for the 0th field]: layer.setEditType(0, QgsVectorLayer.Hidden)

Comment: Your second approach to select the field as a "hidden" widget type in the attributes form does not work for me in QGIS 3.12 on a GeoPackage layer any more. I posted a new, easier approach as separate answer.

Comment: This is not working, the field is still visible through the attribute table

Answer (score 5):

I found this via [HasT](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/9276/hast)'s answer, but in QGIS 2.6.1-Brighton it's:

1. Layer Properties
2. Fields
3. 'Edit widget' column
4. Text Edit
5. 'Hidden' from the list box (found this last step misleading since there are no other options, you just hit OK)

If your attribute table was already open, you'll have to close it and reopen it to see the changes.

If anyone knows how to batch the hiding fields steps, please comment. Kind of annoying when there's a ton of fields to hide!

Comment: For batch hiding fields then this question proposes a python method: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/190843/how-to-hide-more-than-one-qgis-attribute-field-at-a-time

Answer (score 5):

Hiding of attribute fields got easier recently. According to v3.10 of the [documentation on hiding of columns](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#hiding-and-organizing-columns-and-enabling-actions) you can change the visibility of a column directly from the attribute table:

> By right-clicking in a column header, you can choose to hide it from the attribute table.

Comment: although strictly speaking, this works for the Attribute table, a user can still see all fields when identifying a feature with the Identify Features tool.