# Control visibility of specific fields of a PBF file

Tags: qgis-3, fields-attributes, pbf

I downloaded a PBF file from [GeoFabrik](http://download.geofabrik.de/) (OpenstreetMap data) and loaded it into QGIS 3.14.

It gives me each a layer for lines, multilinestrings, multipolygons, points and another one called "other relations". Inside the multipolygon layer under the fields tab I see a differentiation of buildings, lakes and such. Since I will not be using all of the data inside each layer but only selected fields of it, how can I set the visibility for each field?

To be clear: I do not want to hide the fields in a way so I will not see them in the attributes table but I want some fields not to appear in the map canvas.

I tried [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72447/setting-visibility-of-columns-of-attribute-table-in-qgis) but it did not work for me as the data of all fields was still visible (in both the attributes table and the canvas)

Comment: Are you asking, how to categorize a layer and not to display certain categories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found that this can be achieved not under the fields tab of your layer properties or the attributes table but under layer properties > symbology > select "categorized" at the very top of the dialogue instead of single band > select a value > press the classify button and then you can set styles for each field.